# Get two merged bitmap from canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have two bitmaps which are drawn in one canvas side by side.How do i get the merged bitmaps again. I think it is not possible to get them from canvas. What are the other options to get the bitmap of the merged bitmap from the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the bitmap object of merged bitmaps .

first of all create a canvas with a blank bit map

```
 Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
 Bitmap bitmap_object = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf); 
 Canvas canvas_object = new Canvas(bitmap_object);
```

now draw your bitmaps on this **canvas_object** using **drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)** api,

now use the **bitmap_object** to get merged bitmap..